# Can't open pdf in file explorer [Event Finder ID:10001]

Tags: windows-explorer, pdf

Despite the fact, that I just downloaded a correct pdf with its name being complete from the internet this error will appear for every pdf I downloaded in the past and recently:

Windows can't find 'C:\path...\Downloads\xy.pdf' Make sure you have typed the name correctly, then try again:

[image]

As aforementioned, the file has the correct name, I could even open it in the Browser but once I download it and want to open it in the File Explorer application it will not work.

The error Message from the event finder looks like the following:

```
Unable to start a DCOM Server: Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_44.19041.1023.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge.AppXxat4m5y1bf9ghax409y1vwyatpqea4s8.mca as Unavailable/Unavailable. The error:

"2147942402"

Happened while starting this command:

"C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe" -ServerName:MicrosoftEdge.AppXdnhjhccw3zf0j06tkg3jtqr00qdm0khc.mca

Event ID:10001
```

Apparently it has something to do with the MicrosoftEdge browser. I uninstalled it previously before this event happened, is there another way to open pdfs without the ME-browser?

Or am I wrong with this assumption and it is a different error? If so, I would be glad to hear your ideas how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Microsoft Edge legacy, which is deprecated.
It's possible that you have uninstalled it, but it's still marked as
the PDF viewer.

To change the viewer:

- Run
  *Settings > Apps > Default apps > Choose default applications by f‌ile type*
- Scroll down to `.pdf` and click on the handler on the right
- In the dialog of "Choose default applications by f‌ile type",
  select your preferred PDF viewer
- If you wish to select Microsoft Edge, then select:
  "Microsoft Edge
  Recommended for Windows 10""